# Efficient statistical test to compare two multivariate distributions

Tags: statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am looking for a test to assert the "equality" of two multivariate discrete distributions, $\mathbf{A}=\{A_1,\dots,A_k\}$ and $\mathbf{B}=\{B_1,\dots,B_k\}$ for which I do observe two samples $a_1,\dots,a_N$ and $b_1,\dots, b_M$.

I know about the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) test for univariate distributions
and the same wikipedia page I linked provides some pointers to extensions to the multivariate case.

However I'd like to know if an efficient version does exist (and maybe it is already implemented in some software). What do I mean by efficient? something whose complexity could be linear in the number of instances or exploiting statistics that could have very likely been already computed (like $\mathbf\mu_{\mathbf{A}}$ or $\mathbf\mu_{\mathbf{B}}$).

**UPDATE**
I am looking for a distribution agnostic test, meaning that no big assumption can be done on the two multivariate distributions. At the moment I am dealing with binary data, i.e. $A_{i}, B_{i}\in\{0, 1\}, i=1,\dots,k$ and my aim is to be able to determine how to say to samples are drawn from the same distributions in order to apply some analogies from one to the other.

Comment: You should give more information about the situation this data arises. Multivariate distributions can differ in many possible ways, to choose a test we need to know which form of departure from equality is most important!

Comment: see updated question, @kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: Check out the R packages "kSamples" or "energy". They both run various distribution tests and you should be able to find something that satisfies your needs. You might also want to check out distance-based method such as PERMANOVA or MRPP.

Comment: If the data is binary, do you mean $A_i \in \{0,1\}$ at the end, rather than $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Silverfish yeah I meant binary, but wrote it wrong, updating the question

Comment: Does this one help? https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/aa3c/cba3ecab69cb51e53276a1d7597461104404.pdf