# How to test if binary vectors come from different underlying distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis

I have 2 sets of 288 dimension vectors. The elements in these vectors may take values of either 0 or 1. I want to try and show that these vectors come from different underlying distributions. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You need to clarify what your data is. If you say set of 288 dimension set, do you mean you have one single sample from a 288 dimensional distribution in each case? An example for this would be answers to different yes/no questions from the same individual. Or do you have 288 independent and identically distributed observations from a binary distribution in each case? This would be the case when throwing one coin 288 times and recording the results. The multivariate analysis tags suggests the former.

Comment: @Erik Yes, it is the former. I have 30/31 observations in each of the two sets (these are observations taken daily for 1 month). Each observation is 288 dimensional. I hope this clarifies?

Comment: This question is a special case of an earlier asked question in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152795/efficient-statistical-test-to-compare-two-multivariate-distributions